# Android Room: boilerplate codes

Tags: android, android-room

We are working on a new Android app and we decided to use Android Room.
But there are something I don't understand.

1. In Google's tutorial, they create database like this:

   `@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1)
   public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
   public abstract WordDao wordDao();
   }`

In fact we have hundreds of entities, so that means I have to include every single entity in the annotation ? Is there better way to include them automatically ?

2. Also in Google's tutorial, we get a dao like this:

   `WordRepository(Application application) {
       WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
       mWordDao = db.wordDao();
       mAllWords = mWordDao.getAllWords();
   }`

That's because they did this :

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

   public abstract WordDao wordDao();

   private static volatile WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

   static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
...
```

Same question here, to get `wordDao`, I need to declare the abstract method in `WordRoomDatabase`, imagine I have hundreds of entities (so hundreds of DAO) ? Is there a way to get directly the dao from db without declaring ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to get the DAOs from the DB in your code, as the DAOs need to be there at compile time.  You might be able able to do something with an annotation processor, but it would be time consuming and fragile to write.  I'm more curious what you're doing that requires hundreds of entities-  it sounds like you're doing something really unusual or wrong to get that, or you're using the wrong type of database.  Hundreds of entities is something I'd expect of an ERP system, not a mobile app.

Comment: So I have to list all DAOs like this: "public abstract WordDao wordDao()" ? That's not neat for me

Comment: You can try going the annotation processor route, but if you aren't familiar with writing one it will take 10x the time.  And it will be fragile-  getting versioning to work correctly for subsequent uses would be a difficult problem in and of itself.  Java doesn't support runtime creation of classes.

Comment: As @GabeSechan mentioned, why would you need 100 dao? That means 100 tables in your db. In case if you are exaggerating the number and have actually like 10-20 entities then I guest there is no hustle in doing as recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were facing the same problem and just created a new Android library that did all the work for you and generates all these boilerplate codes.

https://github.com/msbelaid/LivingRoom

For example: just add `@Crudable` to your entities, [LivingRoom](https://github.com/msbelaid/LivingRoom) will do the work for you.

One inconvenient, is that the library do not support migrations yet.

If you need more control on your database, just generate the needed classes with the library and copy theme in a new project.